# Is qualifying the verb RESCHEDULE with the phrase "for another time" a redundancy?

Tags: verbs, semantics

The way I see it, the meaning **for another time** is built into the verb **reschedule** and as such, it seems like a redundancy to include it explicitly. Naturally, if the specific new time frame were mentioned, it would bear outright inclusion. I recently came across the statement **Our class has been rescheduled for another time** and changed it to simply **Our class has been rescheduled**. Since the new time frame wasn't given, I saw no point in gilding the lily with unnecessary words.

Comment: Theoretically, an appointment could have been removed from a schedule, and then *rescheduled* for the same time. That's a pretty contrived example; usually when things are rescheduled, they're rescheduled for another time. So it may be redundant, but that might not be a problem.  Repetition and rephrasing is often useful for ensuring that the audience understands correctly.  See, for instance [legal doublet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_doublet)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, this was no type of doublet - it was an amateur translation into English from Russian from a learner in an English-learning forum.

Comment: It doesn't sound unnatural, or like an obvious translation to me.  I can easily imagine a native speaker writing "rescheduled for another time." As you say, it's not necessary, but it also isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: Thank you)) I guess I'm just on high alert for redundancies.

Comment: As you could reschedule for another time or another *day*, it may not be clutter. Also, without a new time frame, your class has not been rescheduled -- maybe canceled pending reschedule.

Comment: Or it may have been rescheduled for a new time frame that hasn't been communicated to you yet.

Comment: It's certainly a redundancy. However, the notion that some people have that redundancies are wrong per se is ... wrong. Here, as a native speaker, I'd say that it sounds idiomatic to my ears. I wouldn't use it myself, though, or at least not often.  Perhaps the unadorned verb is felt to sound a little stark, abrupt. There is the pragmatic, hedging effect. // 'Time' here by default means 'time-slot on some unspecified day, probably not today' not '_time of day_ as opposed to _some other day_'. Maybe this afternoon, maybe next month.

Comment: If this is about an amateur translation into English from Russian from a learner in an English-learning forum, why does it belong here and not, more obviously, somewhere like English Language Learners SE?

Ignoring that you're wholly correct and "… for another time…" is redundant.

Comment: Because I'M a native English speaker and I'm questioning my reasoning - not here on behalf of the student. If anything, he just prompted my doubts.

Comment: It's also possible to reschedule an appointment for a different *group of people* or *venue*, while keeping it at the same day or time. The phrase *schedule a meeting* includes more information than just a day or time.